# Ruby str.match(regex) returns MatchData containing only first matched item

Tags: regex, ruby-2.2

**Using Ruby 2.2**

I have strings like following:

- Weekly on Tuesday and Friday
- Weekly on Monday, Wednesday and Saturday
- Monthly every 2 weeks on Monday

To extract the days of week from above shown strings I have written following regex:

```
/\b(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\b/
```

When trying to use `String#match` instance method the match_data doesn't return all matches. For e.g. please refer the irb output shown below wherein when the string `Weekly on Tuesday and Friday` is matched against above shown regex the `MatchData` contains just `Tuesday`. I expected it to contain `Friday` too.

```
  2.2.1 :001 > str = "Weekly on Tuesday and Friday"
  => "Weekly on Tuesday and Friday" 
  2.2.1 :002 > regex = /\b(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\b/
  => /\b(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\b/ 
  2.2.1 :003 > str.match(regex)
  => #<MatchData "Tuesday" 1:"Tuesday"> 
  2.2.1 :004 > match_data = str.match(regex)
  => #<MatchData "Tuesday" 1:"Tuesday"> 
  2.2.1 :005 > match_data.captures
  => ["Tuesday"]
```

Can anybody please explain me why the MatchData contains only the first matched term when I haven't used any start/end anchors in my Regex? I am sure my regex misses something but I am unable to figure out.

**Note**

Rubular shows correct match groups for the same regex as can be seen at http://rubular.com/r/XZmrHPkjEk

Comment: Did you try using `str.scan(/\b(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\b/)` ? Is it what you are looking for? http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.scan.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes `str.scan(regex)` returns desired results. But I need to understand why `str.match(regex)` is not returning all matches.

Comment: Because it's not supposed to? Regexp#match just returns a match for the regex. Your regex only looks for a single day of the week and is matched as such.

Comment: @ChrisHeald In that case can you please suggest the fix in my regex such that it repeatedly matches days of week present in the string. I tried using the repetition quantifiers in my regex but it seems like I am making some mistake in using those along with the word boundary.

Comment: You can't get an arbitrary number of match group results out of Regexp#match. You can get the entire substring which matches multiple days, but not individual captures of the days. You need to be using #scan for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `MatchData` returned by [`.match()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-match) method only returns the first match with all captured groups if any. I have just tested it and I only could get 1 match with `.match()`.

See [Regular-Expressions.info](http://To%20test%20if%20a%20particular%20regex%20matches%20(part%20of)%20a%20string,%20you%20can%20either%20use%20the%20=~%20operator,%20call%20the%20regexp%20object's%20match()%20method,%20e.g.:%20print%20%22success%22%20if%20subject%20=~%20/regex/%20or%20print%20%22success%22%20if%20/regex/.match(subject).) details:

> To test if a particular regex matches **(part of)** a string, you can
>   either use the =~ operator, call the regexp object's match() method,
>   e.g.: print "success" if subject =~ /regex/ or print "success" if
>   /regex/.match(subject).

Also, from [here](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ruby/regex_cheat_sheet/):

> `String.=~(Regexp)` returns the starting position of the first match or
>   nil if no match was found

To obtain all matches, you need to use [`.scan()`](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.scan) method.