# Why does match find only 1 group in this ruby regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
str = "\r\n <span>60 %</span>\r\n <br>\r\n40 %"
```

And I want to extract the 2 percentage, so I wrote this:

`str.match(/(\d{1,2}\s%)/)`

but it only returns the first one and can't understand why:

`=> #<MatchData "60 %" 1:"60 %">`

If I try this in rubular it works.

[rubular version](http://rubular.com/r/PtLDC1B6mP)

Comment: You need to set `g` (global) flag for your regex: [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993662/whats-the-difference-between-scan-and-match-on-ruby-string

Comment: @Valijon, Ruby ain't got no `/g` option, just `/i`, `/m`, `/x` and `/o`.

Comment: And if it did, that wouldn't change the behavior of the method `match`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661550/ruby-str-matchregex-returns-matchdata-containing-only-first-matched-item

Answer (score 2):

Use [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) instead of the `match`, which only will find the first match.

```
str.scan(/(\d{1,2}\s%)/)
```

Will produce array of matches

```
["60 %", "40 %"]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @sawa is right. You need to add a sentence (or a clause `..match, which only...`) and please capitalize the first word of a sentence.

Comment: ciabon, if you'll be using the percentages in calculations, `str.scan(/\d+(?=\s+%)/).map(&:to_i) #=> [60,40]` might be better. `(?=\s+%)` is a *positive lookahead*. There must be a match on it, but it is not treated as part of the match returned. In fact, if there are no other digits, `str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) #=> [60,40]` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. `match` finds the first match.

Comment: This does not help to achieve the intended outcome: `And I want to extract the 2 percentage`.

Comment: @NicNilov That is not the question. And don't cheat. Don't change what was asked. You are not the OP.

Comment: I provided an exact quote from the original message so you know what I'm talking about. And I edited the title of the question to better reflect its nature. In my opinion this is more helpful than pedantic but useless replies. Consider this common sense, not cheating.

Comment: @Nic, you could leave a comment on the question or propose an edit, but you have no business changing the title to reflect what you think the OP had in his/her head. Moreover, it is, for good reason, against the rules to change a question after answers have been given. For all we know, the OP may be well aware of `scan`, and is just confused about `match`. It's important that questions be answered. Anything beyond that is gravy.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate that.

Comment: @Nic, +1 for your reply. All to often those who have their wisdom challenged on SO defend their position to their last drop of blood or stalk away in a huff, sure signs of a small mind.